# Tagged Unions in Elm

Tags: elm

I'm reading http://elm-lang.org/guide/model-the-problem and want to better understand Tagged Unions in Elm. Specifically I came across this example:

```
type Scale = Normal | Logarithmic
type Widget
    = ScatterPlot (List (Int, Int))
    | LogData (List String)
    | TimePlot Scale (List (Time, Int))
```

The way I think it's interpreted is as follows:

1. `Scale` is a type with 2 possible values: `Normal` or `Logarithmic`
2. `Widget` is a type with 3 possible values: `ScatterPlot`, `LogData`, or `TimePlot`

However, how do I interpret the `(List (Int, Int))` part in `ScatterPlot`? Similarly, how do I interpret the `Scale (List (Time, Int))` part in `TimePlot`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`List` is a built-in type, taking one parameter (another type) and meaning "a list containing values of this type as its elements". So `List (Int, Int)` is a list of `(Int, Int)`. So what's `(Int, Int)`?

In general any `(a, b)` is a tuple with members of type `a` and type `b`. A tuple is a bit like a record without field names, so you can only distinguish elements by their position - however unlike a list the elements can be of different types. So `(Int, Int)` is a tuple containing two `Int`s, where `Int` is just an integer.

Thus, `List (Int, Int)` is a list of tuples of two integers.

With `TimePlot` you've actually got two different type parameters - `Scale` and `List (Time, Int)`. The latter should now make sense given the explanation of `List (Int, Int)` - just the tuple has `Time` as its first type instead of `Int`.

So `TimePlot` takes two types as parameters, and it becomes a `TimePlot Scale (List (Time, Int))`.

In Elm and related languages, type notation (and function application) are defined such that any expression `a b c d` means `a` with parameters `b`, `c`, and `d`. If `c d` is meant to be one parameter it is put in parentheses.

As Andreas says, think of the union 'tags' as functions - they really are, in fact they're called "type constructors". `TimePlot` is a function taking a `Scale` and a `List (Time, Int)` and returning a `Widget`. `Normal` is a function with no parameters which returns a `Scale`, and so on.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation - this makes perfect sense! I think part of the confusion I had was with how the parentheses were being used, but your explanation has cleared that up!

Comment: another related question but how would you interpret this type annotation: `String.toInt : String -> Result String Int`? The way I'm understanding this is that the toInt function takes a `String` as an input and returns a value of type `Result String Int`, right? However, what does a valid value of `Result String Int` look like?

Comment: A `Result error value` is a type which indicates the result of an operation. In this case, `error` is `String` and `value` is `Int`, so if the operation didn't succeed you get a `String` - probably an error message - and if it did you get an `Int`. This is a discriminated union type, so you can pattern match against it - the success branch is `Ok` and the error branch is `Err`. See http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/3.0.0/Result

Comment: just to confirm, then valid values of the type `Result String Int` could be: `Error "404 happened"` and `Ok 200` right? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Correct. The `Ok` branch will carry the value you wanted to get, and the `Error` branch usually has some kind of explanation related to why you can't have it.

Comment: Thanks so much @matthew-walton

Answer (score 1):

Just think about them as function signatures. So Scatterplot must be created like this

```
ScatterPlot [(1,1), (2,2)]
```

and when you pattern match this in a `case` statement

```
case widget of 
  ScatterPlot l -> l -- l is from type (List (Int, Int)) 
  LogData l -> l -- l is from type  (List String)
  TimePlot l -> l -- l is from type Scale (List (Time, Int))
```